# Epoch 1/2 103/Unknown - 8s 80ms/step - loss: 0.0175 (model.fit() keeps running forever even after crossing the total number of training images)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder

I am developing autoencoder on the dataset  https://www.kaggle.com/jessicali9530/celeba-dataset.

```
import tensorflow
tensorflow.__version__
```

---

Output:

```
'2.2.0-rc3'
```

---

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
data_gen = image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255)

batch_size = 20

train_data_gen = data_gen.flow_from_directory(directory=train_dest_path,
                                              target_size=(256, 256),
                                             batch_size=batch_size,
                                             shuffle=True,
                                              class_mode = 'input')
test_data_gen = data_gen.flow_from_directory(directory=test_dest_path,
                                             target_size=(256,256),
                                            batch_size=batch_size,
                                            shuffle=True,
                                             class_mode= 'input')
# autoencoder 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam, SGD

#parameters
inchannel = 3 
x, y  = 256, 256
input_img = Input(shape=(x,y,inchannel))

def autoencoder_model(input_img):
    #encoder 
    conv1 = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(conv1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool1)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(conv2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool2)

    #decoder 
    conv4 = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv3)
    pool3 = UpSampling2D(size=(2,2))(conv4)
    conv5 = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool3)
    pool4 = UpSampling2D(size=(2,2))(conv5)
    decoded = Conv2D(3, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool4)
    return decoded

model = Model(inputs=input_img, outputs=autoencoder_model(input_img))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=Adam())
model.summary()
```

---

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 256, 256, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 256, 256, 32)      896       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 128, 128, 32)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 128, 128, 64)      18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 64, 64, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 64, 64, 128)       73856     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 64, 64, 128)       147584    
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d (UpSampling2D) (None, 128, 128, 128)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 128, 128, 64)      73792     
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_1 (UpSampling2 (None, 256, 256, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 256, 256, 3)       1731      
=================================================================
Total params: 316,355
Trainable params: 316,355
Non-trainable params: 0
```

---

```
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

epochs = 2
num_training_steps = train_data_gen.samples/batch_size
checkpoint_directory = '/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks'

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(checkpoint_directory, verbose=1, save_weights_only=False, save_freq='epoch')
model.fit(train_data_gen, epochs=epochs, verbose=1, callbacks=[checkpoint])
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/2
    103/Unknown - 8s 80ms/step - loss: 0.0175
```

After spending a lot of time, I am still not able to understand why I am getting "Unknown" in the output of model.fit(). Also, model.fit() keeps running forever even though if I take only 1000 images from the training dataset in `flow_from_directory()`. It goes above 1000 and I am not able to understand why it is acting like that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When executing model.fit with a generator as input you have to set the `steps_per_epoch` argument. For generators you can't know the number of images they output (and in this case they go on forever), so set it to the number of images in your dataset divided by your batch size.

Comment: Actually I think its a bug, ImageDataGenerator is a Sequence and it has a defined length, so model.fit is not using it . fit_generator definitely uses it, so its a bug in the implementation of fit

Comment: In the tf 2.1 it shows warning to use fit instead of fit_generator.

Comment: @Akash, in tf v2.3.0, fit_generator is deprecated. "It will be removed in a future version. [...] Please use Model.fit, which supports generators."